# SSRS - Repeat tablix on top of the page

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have 4 different tablix connected to the same data source. I'm trying to put every tablix on the top of the page when one of the tablix is done displaying the data. So in theory, I would have 4 pages in total. I made sure that every tablix kept everything on one page if possible in the Tablix properties. However, I can't figure out how to all of the tablix on top of the page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a rectangle between each tablix. Make the rectangle's height as small as possible, the width is  not important. Then set a page break on the rectangle. Place the rectangle close the the following tablix (1 pt away is perfect).

Also in the report properties, set the consume contain whitespace property to true.

If this does not help, edit your question and show what it looks like now

Comment: This did the trick but I can't get rid off the blank pages. I can't find ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to set it to True. I've already checked the body properties but no luck. Any clues?

Comment: Actually, I found it and ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace it is set to True but it didn't get rid off the blank pages.

Comment: Is there a different way to keep all of the tablix on top of the page without adding rectangles?

Comment: Don't have page break in anything other than the rectangles and it should be ok, make sure they are narrow enough to fit with the report and body width

Comment: I thought you said width wasn't important or what do you mean body width? I made sure all rectangles have a page break.

Comment: The width of the rectangles is not that important but if they are very wide they may cause horizontal blank pages (2 pages wide) so it's worth checking that the tables and rectangles are smaller than the body/report width taking into account margins. I can;t check right now but make sure nothing else has page breaks set and that he rectangle only have a break after not a break before (there may not be an option for both I can't remember, plus it's 1.25AM here so my memory is not optimum! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is the whitespace between your tables and the page breaks are at the end of the tablix.

When tablix1 ends it goes to a new page, then you have that blank space, and then it puts tablix2.

Move tablix2 to be right under Tablix1. If tablix1 is 1 in tall, Tablix 2's location should be 1 in.
[image]

Comment: I think your suggestion works better for my issue. But one problem, when there's no data to display in any of the tablix, all of the tablix shows on one page. Is there any way to separate them on different pages?